# Crawler error expecting keyword end

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nokogiri

I am re posting a specific question.  The original question is at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23480242/nokogiri-problems-parsing-html?noredirect=1#comment36006044_23480242

I am reposting because this crawler is a different one and I think the fix is simple even though I can not figure it out.  My crawler code is:

```
module NoMoreRackCrawler
        class << self
                def noko_doc
                        Nokogiri::HTML(open('http://www.nomorerack.com/'))
                end

                def update
                        doc = self.noko_doc

                        doc.css('.deal').each do |deal|
                                title = deal.css('.display').css('p').children.text
                                deal_price = deal.css('.display').css('.pricing').css('ins').children.first.text.gsub("$","").to_f
                                retail_price = deal.css('.display').css('.pricing').css('del').children.first.text.gsub("$","").gsub(" Retail","").to_f
                                image_url = deal.css('img').first.attr('src')
                                url = "http://www.nomorerack.com#{deal.css('.image a').attribute('href').value}"

                                deal = Deal.where( title: title, source: "No More Rack" ).first_or_create
                                deal.category = "Deal Sites"
                                deal.deal_price = deal_price
                                deal.retail_price = retail_price
                                deal.image_url = image_url
                                deal.url = url
                                deal.save
                        end
                end
                        module Home
                        def self.update
                                doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open("http://www.nomorerack.com/daily_deals/category/home"))
                                NoMoreRackCrawler::update_for_doc( doc, "Home" )
                        end

        end
end
```

and I am getting an error for the second url(http://www.nomorerack.com/daily_deals/category/home) block. My error message is:

```
SyntaxError: /webservices/crawler/app/crawlers/no_more_rack_crawler.rb:33: syntax error, unexpected end-of-input, expecting keyword_end
/webservices/crawler/lib/tasks/crawlers.rake:37:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

my end is there and I have even tried removing and adding an end to see if that fixes it.  Any ideas with my probably silly syntax error?  Thanks for any help and advice.

Comment: Can you please format it properly with soft-tab 2 spaces?

Comment: And if you formatted the code properly you would see that there's `end` missing to `module Home`

Comment: Ahh I see it! Thank you I will try Monday when I get to the office and let update this post.